# Recursive SQL query that finds path

Tags: sql, postgresql, unix, recursion, path

i am trying to solve this problem and i am given a database table such as: create table file(id int, parentid int, name varchar(1024), size int, type 
char(1));

### I have to write a single (recursive) database query to list FULL PATH of all files. [assume type is either "F" or "D" for file or directory]. Your query should give you similar output to unix command: "find . -type f".

I wrote something like this but, I am not sure if this is what the question is asking for me to do since I am inexperienced in Unix. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_path (path_ids, length, is_visited) AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        ARRAY[node_id, destination_node_id], 
        link_length, 
        node_id = destination_node_id 
    FROM 
        node_links_view 

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        path_ids || d.destination_node_id, 
        f.length + d.link_length, 
        d.destination_node_id = ANY(f.path_ids) 
    FROM 
        node_links_view d, 
        search_path f 
    WHERE 
    f.path_ids[array_length(path_ids, 1)] = d.node_id 
    AND NOT f.is_visited 
) 
SELECT * FROM search_path 
WHERE path_ids[1] = 1 AND path_ids[array_length(path_ids, 1)] = 6 
ORDER BY length;
```

Comment: I think that looking @ the unix stuff I needed to use the variables listed in the question

Comment: this looks like oracle.. recursive cte queries are not supported in mysql

Comment: sorry wrong tag fixed it

Comment: @amdixon, this is not Oracle, since it doesn't support ARRAY keyword and subsripts like `path_ids[1]` are not supported in queries. There is also no `array_length` function on Oracle. It rather is Postgre SQL

Comment: Oracle doesn't use the RECURSIVE keyword - AFAIK that is limited PostgreSQL. Retagging...

Comment: Anyone know what the question means by path